# undefined reference to `_imp___ZN15QSerialPortInfo14availablePortsEv'

Tags: qt, serial-port

I am working on simple app on windows to scan the serial port.
Error:

```
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN15QSerialPortInfo14availablePortsEv'
```

My Code:

```
 foreach(const QSerialPortInfo &info, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
        // do something

    }
```

What does the error mean and how to fix it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: That question is related to "external symbol error" which my error does not have. So I think it is irrelevant.

Comment: I think this should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23335157/undefined-reference-to-imp-zn10httpclient5abortev-and-others

Comment: Thanks katamarayudu. For my case i am using QT5 so i only needed to add "QT += serialport" in my project file. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i only needed to add `QT += serialport` in my project (appname.pro) file.